# Reconnect WebSocket in Angular 5 with Rxjs observable and observer

Tags: websocket, rxjs, angular5

In any case, if my application got disconnected from WebSocket I am not able to reconnect it. I am attaching the sample code please suggest me the idea to how I can reconnect WebSocket and initialize my identity on web socket server again.

I have made my application with the help of this tutorial.

https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/

I have written the same code in my application except for my application requirement.

The tutorial that I have been followed does not have the feature to reconnect the WebSocket in any case like internet break or by some reason our WebSocket server got restart because I am running my WebSocket server with SupervisorD and it will automatically restart if WebSocket server get to stop in any case

My application is in production and many customers are using now so I can not change all flow and recreate the code for WebSocket in this application.

I am adding all code that I am using

websocket.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
  connected: boolean = false;
  initialized: boolean= false;
  constructor() { }

  private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
   if (!this.subject) {
    this.subject = this.create(url);
    // console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
   }
   return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

   // here i am trying to reconnect my websocket
   // setInterval (function () {
   //   if (ws.readyState !== 1) {
   //     ws = new WebSocket(url);
   //     this.initialized = false;
   //   }
   //   console.log(this.initialized);
   //   if (ws.readyState == 1 && this.initialized == false) {
   //     ws.send('{"type":"add", 
    "t":"14bfa6xxx", "from_numbers": 
    ["xxxx","xxxxx"], "platform":"xxxx"}');
     //     this.initialized = true;
   //   }

   //   console.log(this.initialized);
   // }, 4000);
    let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
     (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
     ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return ws.close.bind(ws);
     })
    let observer = {
    next: (data: Object) => {
     if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      if (data['type'] == 'add') {
        console.log("Connection Initialized");
        }
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }
    }
    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
   }

   }
```

Chat.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  public messages: Subject<Message>;

  constructor(wsService: WebsocketService, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.messages = <Subject<Message>>wsService
      .connect(socket_url)
      .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      });
  }
}
```

and finality I have used this in our component to subscribe message.

```
constructor(private chatService: ChatService,) {
    this.socketMessages();
}

socketMessages() {
    this.chatService.messages.subscribe(msg => {
      console.log(msg)
    });
  }
```